# Give the area chart the actual color

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Am representing an area, giving it different colors patterns but the line is taking the actual color while the area is taking a lighter shade of the color. i.e

[image]

This is not the kind of behavior I want, I want the areas to have the actual color and not the lines.

[image]

It is the same color for the lines but the lighter shade is represented on the area chart.

How can I make the color look exactly the same in C3js?

Here is the snippet of code that plots the chart.

```
c3.generate
  bindto: '#tasks_backlog'
  size:
    height: 240
  data:
    x: 'Date Completed'
    columns: data
    type: 'area'
    groups: [
      ['3+ Days Requested Tasks', 'Sales Management', 'Service Management', 'Proactive Management', 'Requested Tasks']
  ]
  color:
    pattern: ['#F78768', '#FDD271', '#0DD89D', '#5098EE', '#809DCC', '#FCFCFC']
  axis:
    x:
      type: 'timeseries'
      padding:
        right: -10
        left: 10
      tick:
        format: '%d/%m'
  legend: show: false
```

Comment: It would help if you had some code samples you could post here, so we can see how this works.
What chart library are you using?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen Updated the question to include the snippet.

Comment: isn't that just an opacity added to the area fill? Probably, you can override the css rule?

Comment: Hmm...trying that @kmandov

Comment: It looks like it's using pastel colors. Is there an option you can set to use a palette or a style?

Comment: Thanks, guys, @kmandov 's suggestion worked. I just needed to override the css class of `.c3-area` giving it `opacity: 1 !important`. Thanks

Comment: great! Happy to hear that it worked out for you!